# Setting up new PC. Need to build VS2015 C++ code. Must I install VS2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I'm setting up a new PC and want to install as few versions of Visual Studio as possible.  My requirement is that I must still be able to build VS2015 projects as 2015 -- that is, without updating the toolset of the projects

On my old PC, I can build VS2015 code in VS2017 without upgrading the toolset.  But I don't know if that is because I already had VS2015 installed when I added VS2017 or if VS2017 can just build as 2015 code by itself without upgrading the projects

So what version of Visual Studio must I start with on the new PC?  VS2017 or VS2015?

I realize I can go back and install 2015 afterwards but I'd like to go in order, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm 99% sure that you can install VS15 build tools in VS17! (99% because I've recently updated to VS19 and you certainly can there and, IIRC, it was the same for VS17).

After 'default' installation of VS17, you can then reopen "Visual Studio Installer" to modify the components installed: go to the "Individual Components" tab and scroll down until you come across "MSVC v140 - VS 2015 C++ build tools (v14.00)" and check that.

You may also need similar "v140" special packs if your projects use stuff like MFC or ATL - these are located in the same list, further down.

Comment: PS: Why don't you go 'the whole hog', and upgrade to VS19? You can then add VS15 (for sure) and VS17 build tools if you want. And you can even still get the VS17-for-XP toolset!

Comment: That's actually what I ended up doing.  Went straight to VS2019 and managed to find the tools.

I did have one problem.  One of my post-build steps apparently needed an older version of the msdia120.dll that I didn't seem to get with my VS2019 install options -- even after installing the v140 tools.  I basically had to copy the dll over from my old box and register it manually.  Other than that, it's perfect.  Appreciate the answer